# pandas Series: calculate means between neighbours

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have pandas Series and want to compute means between elements that are neighbours.

For example `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` would give the result `[1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) for this:

```
S = pd.Series(range(1,10))
S1 = S.rolling(2).mean().dropna()
```

Output:

```
1    1.5
2    2.5
3    3.5
4    4.5
5    5.5
6    6.5
7    7.5
8    8.5
```